# How to create an animated GIF from JPEGs in Android (development)

Tags: android, animation, jpeg, adt, gif

I am looking for a simple way to **create** an animated GIF in a native Android application.
The source files should be JPEG (from camera or what ever) and the output should be saved as GIF on the device.

**I do not want to know how to play animations or animated GIF files.**

To be clear: I want to know how to put single images frame by frame into a "movie" and then save it as a .gif file.

e.g. [This App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.listen5.gif) can do want I want to do.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/dragon66/android-gif-animated-writer) is my standalone animated GIF writer for Android. It's quick and you can choose to dither for better quality.

Comment: @dragon66 Can you please add a release tag so we can use JitPack?

Comment: @TheRealChx101 there is no release yet

Comment: @dragon66 Make one then :)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

See this solution.

https://github.com/nbadal/android-gif-encoder

It's an Android version of this post.

http://www.jappit.com/blog/2008/12/04/j2me-animated-gif-encoder/

To use this class, here is an example helper method to generate GIF byte array. Note here the getBitmapArray() function is a method to return all the Bitmap files in an image adapter at once. So the input is all the Bitmap files in one adapter, the output is a byte array which you can write to the file.

```
public byte[] generateGIF() {
    ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps = adapter.getBitmapArray();
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    AnimatedGifEncoder encoder = new AnimatedGifEncoder();
    encoder.start(bos);
    for (Bitmap bitmap : bitmaps) {
        encoder.addFrame(bitmap);
    }
    encoder.finish();
    return bos.toByteArray();
}
```

To use this function, do the following then you can save the file into SDcard.

```
FileOutputStream outStream = null;
        try{
            outStream = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/generate_gif/test.gif");
            outStream.write(generateGIF());
            outStream.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Does this compute a gif with 8-bit or 24-bit colors?

Comment: encoder.addFrame(bitmap); but addFrame looking for image path right ?The method addFrame(Image) in the type AnimatedGifEncoder is not applicable for the arguments (Bitmap)

Comment: @Achayan it should take Bitmap as argument.

Comment: @lifelogger yeah it is and I was using worng one which is the J2ME version. Thanks

Comment: thanks. I used this class. how can I use many frames without OutOfMemoryError?

Comment: Thanks for sharing this code. When I run it though I just get an image, though it says it's a GIF.  I've tested by trying to embed it elsewhere.  Are there any other settings you have to run?

Comment: @scientiffic GIF is a image file as well. If you cannot display it on your phone, you probably need to check this answer down below. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16331504/3047840

Comment: There is an image processing library, akin to http://square.github.io/picasso/ which uses the very same AnimatedGifEncoder class mentioned by Lifelogger-
http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/latest/index.html, https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Comment: this is very slow for me. about 6 seconds for a frame on my nexus 5x. each frame is 1800x1000

Comment: How to declare adapter in adapter.getBitmapArray(); ?

Comment: @djac If you're not already using an adapter, you can just pass a `Bitmap[]` or `Bitmap...` into the method instead and work with that.

Comment: After creating the `encoder`, you may also need to call `encoder.setDelay(YOUR_FRAME_DELAY_MILLIS);` and/or `animatedGifEncoder.setRepeat(0);` - see source code for documentation: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nbadal/android-gif-encoder/master/GifEncoder.java

Comment: Hello,
I successfully used this view in my app but when I am setting GIF by using InputStream only first image is displayed.

Please any suggestion...

Answer (score 7):

This might help you. It's a class which is used to generate gif files.

http://elliot.kroo.net/software/java/GifSequenceWriter/

Comment: There is a way of doing what you want. First make a byte array of images. Then add header information of gif file then save this file.

Comment: Do you have an example? I managed it to save a file from byte array, but I don't know the header information.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/Graphics/GIF/spec-gif89a.txt  FOLLOW THIS. It consists all the header info a gif required. Or wiki git format and find all the header byte info. Then just add those values in your byte array.

Comment: This is not the perfect answer because I haven't a working solution jet, but it is the closest answer to get the bounty...

Comment: Thanks :) I'll try to do the same thing. The ans of this question by user3047840 is just perfect.

Comment: @Jatin Malwal-can you post link for same?

Answer (score 6):

It did very well for me, It create file fast and good quality images

```
//True for dither. Will need more memory and CPU
AnimatedGIFWriter writer = new AnimatedGIFWriter(true);
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("animated.gif");
Bitmap bitmap; // Grab the Bitmap whatever way you can
// Use -1 for both logical screen width and height to use the first frame dimension
writer.prepareForWrite(os, -1, -1)
writer.writeFrame(os, bitmap);
// Keep adding frame here
writer.finishWrite(os);
// And you are done!!!
```

https://github.com/dragon66/android-gif-animated-writer

Comment: One thing about this encoder is it can write the animated gif frame by frame to reduce memory consumption

Comment: is it going to save the gif file too ?

Comment: Yes, it saved the gif with name animated.gif

Answer (score 4):

If you only want to display these bitmaps like an animated gif, you can create an **AnimatedDrawable** using this code:

```
AnimationDrawable animation = new AnimationDrawable();
animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image1), 10);
animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image2), 50);
animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image3), 30);
animation.setOneShot(false);

ImageView imageAnim =  (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imageAnim.setImageDrawable(animation);

// start the animation!
animation.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**

Have you seen this article? ..... it's with source code..

As I know, I think android won't play gif animation image. You should use webview that will play gif animation..

http://droid-blog.net/2011/10/14/tutorial-how-to-use-animated-gifs-in-android-part-1/

and if you can..

http://androidosbeginning.blogspot.in/2010/09/gif-animation-in-android.html

**Solution 2**

Android provides [Drawable Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html).

Comment: Hm... Thanks, but this is just how to play GIFs. But I want to create a new GIF file out of files from my device. I want to know how to but single images frame by frame into a "movie" and then save it as a .gif file. I did not find something like that in your links. Or am I blind? :)

Comment: You should've put this explanation in an EDIT to the original question ;)

Answer (score 0):

Gif is basically a set of images with a constant time delay in frames. You can not directly play gif in android. I've worked lot on playing gif animation in android.

- When playing gif we also handle all calls of playing frames by our
  self.   So this is not a best approach
- If you have set of images just play them by a delay in frames. That
  would be the all you want.
- You can not make gif in application by native code as well. There are
  some drawbacks as well for using gif format. Which I had faced in my game.
- If you have set of drawables you can use  [AnimationDrawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html) for showing aanimation like gif as well. It can also set the any View.

I had also made a custom view to play gif animations. **First I load gif and convert it into InputStream then I pass it to my custom view class to play the gif.**

```
 public class GifWebView extends View {
    private Movie mMovie;
    InputStream mStream;
    long mMoviestart;
    private boolean play;

public GifWebView(Context context, InputStream stream) {
    super(context);
    mStream = stream;
    setPlay(true);
    mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(mStream);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    final long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

    if (mMoviestart == 0) {
        mMoviestart = now;
    }
    final int relTime = (int) ((now - mMoviestart) % mMovie.duration());

    mMovie.setTime(relTime);
    mMovie.draw(canvas, 20, 20);
    if (play) {
        Log.i("reltime", "" + relTime + ",duration:" + mMovie.duration());
        this.invalidate();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent event) {
    return true;
};

public boolean isPlay() {
    return play;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I didn't ask how to play GIF files. I asked how to create GIF files.