# Create animated GIF file (Android developer)

Tags: android, jpeg, adt, gif, animated-gif

I'm developing an Android App and want to **create** a new GIF file out of files from my device. The source files should be JPEG (from camera or what ever) and the output should be saved as a GIF animation on the device. Is that possible? Can someone give me hints how to do that?

Comment: Looks like this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16331437/how-to-create-an-animated-gif-from-jpegs-in-android-development

Comment: Have you seen how's the author of the post? I never got an answer and this is not a solution to create GIF files. It is a how to animate GIF files.

Comment: Then add a bounty or edit the question. Making a new one of the same question is not the correct solution to this.