# Why I don't see the file output in Android?

Tags: android, fileoutputstream

I am creating GIF based on images in Android. I create the .gif file and save it with `FileOutputStream` but I don't see it anywhere on sdcard or in gallery app.

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "test.gif");
    FileOutputStream outStream = null;
    try{
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        outStream.write(generateGIF());
        outStream.close();
        Log.v("Creating gif", "Gif saved");
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
```

generateGIF returns byteArray and everything works without error. 
Did I missed something?

Comment: You may want to log `file.getAbsolutePath()`.

Comment: Creating gif﹕ Gif saved /storage/sdcard0/Pictures/test.gif - it seems it saved, but I don't see it. Do I need some permissions for that?

Comment: Look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16331437/how-to-create-an-animated-gif-from-jpegs-in-android-development) I think this may help

Comment: @Yourange, yep I am using exactly this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MediaScannerConnection` to notify the system of new files. That refreshes the Gallery in case of media files and also the MTP/PTP databases when accessing SD card via USB.

Comment: I was thinking about that, but did't know that MediaScannerConnection also influences MTP/PTP connection. I don't see the gif after phone restart, but I will try adding MediaScanner tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: Yep, that was it. For reading files via Windows Explorer MediaScanner is also needed.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add these tags in the AndroidManifest.xml?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

These tags tell Android that the app would like to access the SD card. Otherwise, Android blocks the request, making it impossible to save the GIF.

Comment: thanks for response, good point, but I already have it, thanks anyway