# Convert Bitmap to javax.microedition.lcdui.Image

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap

I am trying to create a gif from jpeg files using http://www.jappit.com/blog/2008/12/04/j2me-animated-gif-encoder/ and this thread is my reference [How to create an animated GIF from JPEGs in Android (development)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16331437/how-to-create-an-animated-gif-from-jpegs-in-android-development).

```
encoder.start(bos);
    for (Bitmap bitmap : bitmaps) {
        encoder.addFrame(bitmap);
    }
```

But addFrame looks for Image ( The method addFrame(Image) in the type AnimatedGifEncoder is not applicable for the arguments (Bitmap) ) and I am not sure how we can convert Bitmap to .lcdui.Image

Any clues ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have to use gif? Why not animate bitmaps with ObjectAnimator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this class https://github.com/nbadal/android-gif-encoder/blob/master/GifEncoder.java.
As I can see there, `addFrame` method receives `Bitmap` as a parameter.