# Android create gif with image view and gif

Tags: android, gif, animated-gif

What would be the best way to place a gif on top of an image view in Android and then save the result as a gif? It seems to be like Android doesn't really have good gif support at this point, and the best way would be to break the gif up into frames and create a new gif with these frames.

Comment: Do you just want to view a gif? If so then I might have a solution for you.

Comment: i think the main problem is how to combine a gif and an image in android and then be able to save that combination

Comment: Okay then have a look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16331437/how-to-create-an-animated-gif-from-jpegs-in-android-development

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to show a GIF in imageview then you can use this 3rd party library to display GIF

https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable

Try this libs and integrate with your project.

Good Luck