# When sharing Animate Gif to Twitter by using Intent, Twitter makes it static image (Android)

Tags: java, android

When I share animate gif to Twitter by using Intent, Twitter makes it static image.

It works to share to Facebook Messenger.

[How to create an animated GIF from JPEGs in Android (development)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16331437/how-to-create-an-animated-gif-from-jpegs-in-android-development)

I use this class to create Animated gif.
Can anyone help me?

Here is my code below.

```
public byte[] generateGIF(ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    AnimatedGifEncoder encoder = new AnimatedGifEncoder();
    encoder.start(bos);
    for (Bitmap bitmap : bitmaps) {
        encoder.addFrame(bitmap);
    }
    encoder.finish();
    return bos.toByteArray();
}


private void shareGif (byte[] bytes,String fileName) {

    try {
        File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir(), fileName + ".gif");

        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fOut.write(bytes);
        fOut.close();

        file.setReadable(true, false);
        final Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
        intent.setType("image/gif");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent , "Send image using.."));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Taishi, were u able to share gif & text both to fb messenger at the same time?