# How can I convert bitmaps on Xamarin.Android?

Tags: c#, android, image, xamarin, android-camera

1. I want to make app where I can make photos with android camera and
   then convert them into .gif.
2. I tried `NGif` lib but i have exception from `System.Drawing: The
   type initializer for 'Gdip' threw an exception`.

Any help? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you looked at other answers? There's quite a bit on this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16331437/how-to-create-an-animated-gif-from-jpegs-in-android-development

Comment: Yes, i saw most of topics but they're using java libs.

Comment: Most of these Java/Android libs can be bound via a [Java Bindings Project](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/), or ported over using C#.

Comment: How can I map e.g. this class to c#? Link: https://github.com/nbadal/android-gif-encoder/blob/master/GifEncoder.java

Comment: You would recreate this in C# using the respective syntax and C# classes instead of Java ones. However most of these should already be included in the `Xamarin.Android` library. You may want to look at this guide for more help: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/xamarin-for-java/

Comment: Thank you for help, i'll try :)