# Android repetitive decode Bitmap from file

Tags: android, bitmap

To simulate an animation I decode a sequence of frame next to another and update it on a Bitmap at a fixed rate. The problem is everytime the BitmapFactory.decodeFile function get call it allocate new File and FileInputStream objects, this leads to the GC being called very frequently.

So is there a way to effectively decode file in this scenario for Android. Note that caching Bitmap is useless here 'cause the frames loop continuously one after another.

Comment: As long as you use files you have to create a new inputstream for every file. You cannot blame bitmap factory for that.

Comment: So there's no way to reuse the InputStream I guest? Or can you suggest an efficient way to decode bitmap from file repetitively?

Answer (score 0):

You'd better convert the bunch of image files into AGIF format and play it.

Check this post.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20277649/4518710

Comment: Hello! GIF doesn't work for me because I need to draw these Bitmap with OpenGL. What I'm after here is to create animated stickers and overlay them on camera feed.